# Connect Arduino and ESP8266 NodeMCU

Tags: esp8266, web-server

I want to connect multiple sensors and see their measurements via ESP8266 Web Server. But, the problem is that ESP8266 has only one analog pin and I can't connect multiple sensors to it, so i need to connect it to the Arduino. How can i do that?

Comment: you could use I2C ADC module with 4 or 8 analog pins

Comment: How to connect it?

Comment: what? the I2C module? like any other I2C module. usually to D1/D2

Comment: How can I connect the sensors to ESP8266 using I2C module? I'm a beginner, I'm sorry.

Comment: https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-4-channel-adc-breakouts/signal-connections

Comment: Thanks. Helped a lot.